# How to continue the previous work after pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: command-line

I am using terminal of Linux, python 2.7 to train a neural network. While training a deep network I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> unintentionally and it stopped training. Is it possible to continue the training process or not? Do we have any short key or code to tell the system forget about KeyboardInterrupt?

Comment: That highly depends on the software in use, especially how it stores the training progress – please [edit] and add information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short no... When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a signal is sent to the process, and it kills the process that is running in your terminal. You can't resurrect it. All you can do is run it again.

The best you can do is start to retrain your model by running the command again

**EDIT:**

As was discussed in the comments, my oversight may have led to an incorrect answer! After a SIGTERM signal, it is possible to resume the process

**SIGKILL**: Terminates a process immediately. This signal cannot be handled (caught), ignored or blocked. (The `kill -9` command in Linux generates the same signal).

**SIGTERM**: Terminates a process immediately. However, this signal can be handled, ignored or caught in code. If the signal is not caught by a process, the process is killed. Also, this is used for graceful termination of a process. (The `kill` command in Linux if specified without any signal number like -9, will send `SIGTERM`)

So I will defer to dessert's comment left on your original post more information is necessary. Thus I will leave the answer 'no' until further information is provided

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't kill, it politely asks the process to commit suicide... (SIGTERM, not SIGKILL). Most processes comply.

Comment: hmm this seems a bit pedantic :p but looking back, I guess my oversight could possibly lead to an incorrect answer :(. Though from op's post it seemed that his process more than happily complied

Comment: SIGTERM lets the process terminate cleanly: flush buffers, etc...

Comment: and potentially save progress to resume later, yes! @j-money no harm done, just [edit] and correct the post.